# Performance difference between parallel and nested IF conditions

Tags: vb.net

I always assumed that when writing if statements with multiple conditions, parallel way is superior because the compiler could optimize the parallel statements into a SIMD instruction. Today I tested it out of curiosity and got the opposite result. Heres the test code:

```
    Dim iterations As Integer = 100000000
    Dim result1 As New List(Of Boolean)
    Dim result2 As New List(Of Boolean)

    Dim r As New Random
    Dim rvalues As New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 0 To iterations + 8
        rvalues.Add(r.Next(Integer.MinValue, Integer.MaxValue))
    Next

    Dim t1 As Integer = Environment.TickCount

    For i = 0 To iterations
        If rvalues(i) < rvalues(i + 1) Then
            If rvalues(i + 2) < rvalues(i + 3) Then
                If rvalues(i + 4) < rvalues(i + 5) Then
                    If rvalues(i + 6) < rvalues(i + 7) Then
                        result1.Add(True)
                    Else
                        result1.Add(False)
                    End If
                Else
                    result1.Add(False)
                End If
            Else
                result1.Add(False)
            End If
        Else
            result1.Add(False)
        End If
    Next

    t1 = Environment.TickCount - t1

    Dim t2 As Integer = Environment.TickCount

    For i = 0 To iterations
        If rvalues(i) < rvalues(i + 1) And rvalues(i + 2) < rvalues(i + 3) And rvalues(i + 4) < rvalues(i + 5) And rvalues(i + 6) < rvalues(i + 7) Then
            result2.Add(True)
        Else
            result2.Add(False)
        End If
    Next

    t2 = Environment.TickCount - t2

    Dim checkOK As Boolean = True
    For i = 0 To iterations
        If result1(i) <> result2(i) Then checkOK = False
    Next

    MsgBox("nested: " & t1 & " parallel: " & t2 & " checkOK: " & checkOK)
```

The result I'm getting is that the nested method is consistently ~25% faster. All i can conclude is that the parallel method is bottlenecked by fetching the data for all the concurrent comparisons and that there is no optimization going on after all. Is that about right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `If clause1 And clause2 And ...` it has to evaluate every clause. Your nested `If` does not do that. If you used `If clause1 AndAlso clause2 AndAlso ...` then it can stop evaluating at the first clause which evaluates to `False`. [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx) is known as a short-circuiting operator.

Comment: Interesting, I ran the test again after replacing the and's with andalso's and now the parallel option is ~8% faster than the nested. That raises the question though, why does And exist at all if AndAlso does the same and is quicker about it?

Comment: @KarliRaudsepp See the help for `And` and `AndAlso`. You can use `And` as a bit-wise operator, e.g. `1 And 3` is `1`. Also, you should not do timings on debug builds (I'm not saying you did) because the compiler does not make the same optimisations it does with a release build.